# How do I parse this kind of text file with special separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I need to parse the following text file into a dataframe, any suggestion about the methods?

Input:

```
('name:   ', u'Jacky')
('male:   ', True)
('hobby:   ', u'play football and bascket')
('age:   ', 24.0)
----------------
('name:   ', u'Belly')
('male:   ', True)
('hobby:   ', u'dancer')
('age:   ', 74.0)
----------------
('name:   ', u'Chow')
('male:   ', True)
('hobby:   ', u'artist')
('age:   ', 46.0)
```

output:

```
name  male  hobby     age
jacky True  football  24
...
```

Comment: firstly, i want to separate data records, which are separated by '--------------', and Im stucked here in the beginnig

Comment: i have never dealed with this kind of separator

Comment: I'm gonna eat, almost done with the code, you'll get it after lunch

Comment: @Michael Again. Use correct upper-case letters and read links I posted carefully.

Comment: If you're just looking for suggestions: I would use `readlines()` method for file opening, then iterate over line numbers by 5 and use simple parsing functions to parse each type of your line to desired value type

Comment: thanks to everyone who's trying to help me to work out with this, I answer lately because I was studying and testing the solutions that all you gave me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any way to parse this data convention with usage of some existing parser so I suggest to build your own ones. Then I would use `readlines()` method on open file so it allows me to iterate over lines of data and apply correct parser to each row in iteration. Finally, I would combine data and create DataFrame. Example code is below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sys

def parse_from_weird_file_to_pandas_df(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        content = f.readlines()

    name_vals = [_parse_text(content[line]) for line in range(0, len(content), 5)]
    male_vals = [_parse_bool(content[line]) for line in range(1, len(content), 5)]
    hobby_vals = [_parse_text(content[line]) for line in range(2, len(content), 5)]
    age_vals = [_parse_int(content[line]) for line in range(3, len(content), 5)]

    df_rows = zip(name_vals, male_vals, hobby_vals, age_vals)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_rows, columns=["name", "male", "hobby", "age"])
    return df


def _parse_text(text_line):
    text = text_line[text_line.find("u'") + 2: text_line.find("')")]
    return text

def _parse_bool(bool_line):
    val_bool = bool_line[bool_line.find("', ") + 3: bool_line.find(")")]
    return True if val_bool == "True" else False

def _parse_int(int_line):
    val_int = int_line[int_line.find("', ") + 3: int_line.find(")")]
    return int(float(val_int))
```

If you wish to shorten `'play football and bascket'` to just `'football'` you can achieve this for example by creating list with all available hobbies, looping them through parsed hobby and returning the matching one.

Comment: Thank your sir for your help, your solution works perfectly in my usecase. I just have one doubt about the +2 and +3, in the parse functions, I 'm not sure that I understand its meaning.

Comment: `find` method in `text_line.find("u'")` will return index of first character of `u'` string. You need to find index of first letter of text between quotes, so you need to add 2 to the result of `text_line.find("u'")`.Simillar situation is with `bool_line.find("', ")` and +3

Answer (score 0):

I used regex to parse your text file :

```
import re
import pandas as pd
text_path = 'text.txt'
my_dict = {}
pattern = r"\('(\w+):\s+',\s+u*'*([a-zA-Z0-9\s.]*)'*\)"
with open(text_path, 'r') as txt:
    for block in re.split(r"-+\n", txt.read()):
        for line in filter(None, block.split('\n')):
            col_name, value = re.search(pattern, line).group(1,2)
            try:
                value = int(float(value))
            except ValueError:
                value = True if value=='True' else False if value=='False' else value
            if col_name in my_dict:    
                my_dict[col_name].append(value)
            else:
                my_dict[col_name] = [value]
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
print(df)
```

Output :

```
    name  male                      hobby  age
0  Jacky  True  play football and bascket   24
1  Belly  True                     dancer   74
2   Chow  True                     artist   46
```

Booleans values are not string but real bool `True` or `False`, numerical value (like `age`) are `int` (you could keep them as `float`) and not strings.

Ask me if you don't understand something.

Comment: firstly I wanna thank you for you help, I tested it into my dataset and it gives me this kind of error,  [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'] in the line of re.search.group.

Comment: Could you provide the txt file or a part of it that has this error

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick code I made just before lunch, not optimised but seems to work (I did not remove the 'u'in the string and did not convert the int but you should be able to manage that ? If not let me kow and i will work on it after !

The .join remove unecessary char and I assume you only have 4 object every time...

```
    file = open("yourfile.txt", 'r')
    lines = file.readlines()
    init = True
    list_to_append = []
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'male', 'hobby','age'])
    for line in lines:
        if '---' not in line:
            line = line.split(',')[1]
            processed_line = ''.join(c for c in line if c not in " ()'\n")
            list_to_append.append(processed_line)
            if len(list_to_append) == 4:
                df.loc[len(df)] = list_to_append
                list_to_append = []
        else :
            pass
    file.close()
```

Comment: You forgot to close your file with `close()` method

Comment: Your code works well, thank you! For theremaining minor adjustment I can hold it by myself.